# How do you convert from GPS data in WGS84 to a GIS built in NAD27 in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, wgs84, datum

I have GPS data that has been recorded in Datum WGS84.  The client has a GIS built in Datum NAD27.  Having looked into the conversions online I would like to know how to do this rigorously with minimum loss of accuracy.  Ordinarily I would build a GIS in WGS84 that uses GPS data and project it to the desired UTM (16N in this case).  I know I can transform in ArcGIS 10 but is this rigorous enough?

Comment: What kind of GPS do you have ?

Comment: 7 different ones that are all holding data.  All Garmins.  Models 62s, 62, etrex 20, etrex vista HCx.  I'm using DNRGPS to take the data off the GPS units, using no projection.  I'm then defining the projection in Arc Catalog to World>WGS84 and then I was wondering if I should transform at that point and project to NAD27 (but which transformation to use?)

Comment: According to this http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/003r/pdf/geographic_transformations.pdf transformation 18 should be the one.

Comment: You could reproject in the DNRGPS without having to go to striaght to ArcGIS..I dont know why your client has a different built but he or she should be able to fix that by reset to Datum WG84. I am not sure which GPS he or she is using.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @PROBERT would ArcGIS not provide a more rigorous reprojection than DNRGPS?  The client has an existing GIS in NAD27 UTM 16N.  this is not uncommon.  The question is how best to maintain accuracy when adding GPS data recorded in WGS84

Comment: NAD_1927_To_WGS_1984_18 is for Mexico. Is that where the data is located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some information that would have been helpful if you provided: which ArcGIS version do you have? What accuracy is the customer looking for? What location does the data represent?

You might try a few different paths of transformations. I'm going to assume the data is within the contiguous 48 states of the US and a relatively recent version of ArcGIS 10.1.

You can try a single step, file-based transformation, NAD_1927_To_WGS_1984_79_CONUS. This uses the same conus grid file as the NADCON software.

Because the GPS units are all recreational (or mapping) grade receivers, this more complicated workflow may not really improve results. Use a three step transformation: WGS_1984_(ITRF00)_To_NAD_1983_HARN, NAD_1983_To_HARN_(insert appropriate state/region abbreviation here) and finally, NAD_1927_To_NAD_1983_NADCON.

Comment: the data is in Calakmul, Mexico.  And the GIS version (as stated in the original question ;) ) is ArcGIS10.  Using transformation 18 (NADtoWGS) seems to have done the trick.  Thanks for the in depth answer mkennedy.  Much appreciated